# Error al enviar email de verificacion en servidor

Tags: php, laravel, email, mail, mailer

al registrar un usuario en local funciona correctamente el envio de email, pero no en el servidor, y no se qué puede ser
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada, si tienes un servidor web debes buscar la configuración de tu servidor desde el Cpanel o pedirlo al soporte encargado

No puedes usar la configuración de google porque ya tu servidor tiene su propia configuración en donde te arrojan que puerto usan con tls ssl etc..

Para usar la configuración de tu servidor debes tener un correo creado que siempre terminara en @tudominio.com

Si tu servidor es uno compartido y deseas por obligación cambiar al servicio de google debes hablar con el soporte a ver si te lo permiten

Si tu servidor ya es privado debes buscarte un tutorial para cambiar esa configuración(que sinceramente no he visto ni he buscado)

Si manejas Cpanel Ve al apartado de Correos Electrónicos y presiona en Cuentas de correo electrónico, si no tienes uno creado pues créalo, si ya lo tienes a tu derecha aparece la opción connect devices allí te debe aparecer lo necesario para que hagas la conexión con el correo